# Fiddler4 not capturing traffic (FME -> CouchDB)

Tags: couchdb, fiddler

I love Fiddler, and it is a mainstay for my web debugging. It is working fine for all my browser based activities. But right now, I am having a login issue with CouchDB. I am using a desktop software called SAFE FME, which provides login and bulk upload to the CouchDB server. From the browser I can login to the CouchDB, so that did not seem the problem.

All I want to do is see the traffic going between the FME and the CouchDB server.

CouchDB is running on http://localhost:5984/

computer is windows 7, 64 bit. Both Couchdb and FME are local to the computer
I have Fiddler setup for:

- Capture Traffic true
- Any Process

Any idea why I am not capturing the data

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're probably not capturing the data because `SAFE FME` doesn't use the system proxy setting.

Open FME Workbench. From the menu select Tools|FME Options then select Network and check Use Proxy. Ref: https://knowledge.safe.com/articles/How_To/Configure-FME-Desktop-to-connect-through-your-proxy-server

The Fiddler proxy runs on `127.0.0.1` port `8888`.

Comment: I have now tried a couple of things (1) No proxy, (2) Custom Proxy map, (3) use system proxy. None showed any traffic through fiddler. FME staff is working with me. But I am curious. Our default system proxy on each workstation (setup via IE) is http://proxy.<ourcompany>.com:3128 (with username and password). That is the corporate pass-through. I know that that Fiddler chains external Chrome requests through to this proxy, Is there something I am missing about FME?

Comment: I am not saying that is relevant in this case, where everything is supposed to be local, but when I do test external operations, it would be good to know how Fiddler on http://localhost:8888 acts as a proxy chain to before the corporate proxy.

Comment: You should talk to FME about why their "Use system proxy" option is buggy. I presume you started Fiddler before FME (some buggy apps don't notice proxy change events). 

Fiddler adopts the existing system proxy settings as an upstream gateway before it sets itself as the system proxy. It reverses the process on shutdown.

Comment: The SAFE FME folks admit it is their bug, and have added it to their bug fix queue.